# Plank dock undesirable effect when using "Pressure Reveal"

Tags: plank

I am using Plank as my dock for sometime now and it works magnificently. However, I'm experiencing problems when I enable "Pressure Reveal" in the settings. I'm using the "Autohide" settings so Plank hides automatically whenever I point my mouse away the dock, which is as intended. But, clicking the icons in the dock with "Pressure Reveal" enabled does not click the icon at all, it just hides the dock away.

I'm about to post a bug/question on Launchpad but I decided to ask a question here first because apparently, I'm the only one experiencing this bug.

This is the output when running `plank -d` with the option "Pressure Reveal" enabled and "Autohide" selected:

```
[DEBUG 14:29:32.287857] [Gtk] Connecting to session manager
[INFO 14:29:32.290188] [AbstractMain:229] Plank version: 0.11.0
[INFO 14:29:32.290258] [AbstractMain:230] Kernel version: 4.2.0-34-generic
[INFO 14:29:32.290307] [AbstractMain:231] GLib version: 2.46.2 (2.46.2)
[INFO 14:29:32.290362] [AbstractMain:234] GTK+ version: 3.16.7 (3.16.7)
[INFO 14:29:32.290409] [AbstractMain:237] Wnck version: 3.14.0
[INFO 14:29:32.290464] [AbstractMain:238] Cairo version: 1.14.4
[INFO 14:29:32.290511] [AbstractMain:239] Pango version: 1.36.8
[INFO 14:29:32.290557] [AbstractMain:241] + Cairo/Gtk+ HiDPI support enabled
[INFO 14:29:32.290603] [AbstractMain:244] + Dynamic Quicklists support enabled
[INFO 14:29:32.290648] [AbstractMain:247] + XInput Barriers support enabled
[WARN 14:29:32.290703] [Environment:161] XDG_SESSION_CLASS not set in this environment!
[INFO 14:29:32.322545] [WindowControl:68] Window-manager: Compiz
[DEBUG 14:29:32.323346] [DockletManager:201] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-desktop.so'
[INFO 14:29:32.323413] [DockletManager:106] Docklet 'desktop' registered
[DEBUG 14:29:32.323877] [DockletManager:201] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-clock.so'
[INFO 14:29:32.323934] [DockletManager:106] Docklet 'clock' registered
[DEBUG 14:29:32.324389] [DockletManager:201] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-trash.so'
[INFO 14:29:32.324445] [DockletManager:106] Docklet 'trash' registered
[DEBUG 14:29:32.324864] [DockletManager:201] Loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plank/docklets/libdocklet-clippy.so'
[INFO 14:29:32.324916] [DockletManager:106] Docklet 'clippy' registered
[INFO 14:29:32.325045] [AbstractMain:301] Running with 1 docks ('dock1')
[DEBUG 14:29:32.325109] [DockController:79] Create dock 'dock1' (config_folder = /home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1)
[DEBUG 14:29:32.325288] [Settings:53] Bind 'PlankDockPreferences' to '/net/launchpad/plank/docks/dock1/'
[WARN 14:29:32.356097] [Preferences:192] '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' is read-only!
[DEBUG 14:29:32.356153] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme'
[WARN 14:29:32.356308] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'OuterStrokeColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356349] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'FillStartColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356384] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'FillEndColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356419] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'InnerStrokeColor' for group 'PlankTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356453] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'HorizPadding' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356512] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'ItemPadding' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356547] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'IndicatorSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356582] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'IconShadowSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356616] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'UrgentBounceHeight' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356651] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'LaunchBounceHeight' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356685] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'FadeOpacity' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356718] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'ClickTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356752] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'UrgentBounceTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356786] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'LaunchBounceTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356820] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'ActiveTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356854] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'SlideTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356887] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'FadeTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356920] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'HideTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356954] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'GlowSize' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.356987] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'GlowTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.357021] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'GlowPulseTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.357054] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'UrgentHueShift' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.357088] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'ItemMoveTime' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[WARN 14:29:32.357122] [Preferences:384] Missing key 'CascadeHide' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/plank/themes/Transparent/dock.theme' - using default value
[DEBUG 14:29:32.359321] [ItemFactory:176] Loading dock elements from '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.359965] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/pencil.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.360760] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/VSCode.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.361498] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/gimp.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.362154] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/org.gnome.Nautilus.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.362803] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/inkscape.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.363547] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/jetbrains-studio.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.364219] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/google-chrome.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.364959] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/frescobaldi.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.365584] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/uget-gtk.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.366195] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/sublime-text.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.366832] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/blender.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.367477] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/codeblocks.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.368082] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/smplayer.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.368775] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/genymobile-genymotion.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.369446] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/transmission-gtk.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.370147] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/clementine.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.370962] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/gnome-terminal.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.371610] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/ubuntu-software-center.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.372233] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/arduino.2.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.372894] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/minecraft.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.373509] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/jetbrains-clion.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.374171] [Preferences:349] Loading preferences from file '/home/erwinson/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/jetbrains-idea-ce.dockitem'
[DEBUG 14:29:32.449727] [Unity:164] Initalizing LauncherEntry support
[INFO 14:29:32.450458] [HideManager:618] Barriers enabled (XInput 2.3 support)
[DEBUG 14:29:32.450899] [PositionManager:677] Without draw_values there is trouble ahead
[DEBUG 14:29:32.454564] [HideManager:746] Barrier: 23,768 - 1343,768
[DEBUG 14:29:32.458646] [Unity:141] com.canonical.Unity lost
[INFO 14:29:32.620646] [DockRenderer:491] Cairo.SurfaceType: XLIB
[WARN 14:29:34.488547] [SurfaceCache:196] Creating surface took WAY TOO LONG (39ms), enabled downscaling for this cache!
[WARN 14:31:26.410240] [SurfaceCache:196] Creating surface took WAY TOO LONG (31ms), enabled downscaling for this cache!
[WARN 14:31:34.241658] Failed to fetch xids: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.ayatana.bamf.application' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/application/245772064
[WARN 14:31:34.262819] (Services/WindowControl.c:410):plank_window_control_get_num_windows: runtime check failed: (_tmp2_ != NULL)
^C[WARN 14:31:54.959141] [AbstractMain:42] Caught signal (2), exiting
```

Thank you for any help you can give.
By the way, this is the 2nd issue I encountered with Plank. The first one was that clicking Shutdown in the menu logs me out instead (which I already solved by adding a delay in autostarting Plank, which also affected only a few in my POV because searching for a fix was quite a pain). Also I'm using the PPA version (I believe there's one in the official Ubuntu repositories), version 0.11.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, this problem went away when I switched to GNOME Desktop, but GNOME itself is giving me some other weird bugs. My best guess about this would be that Compiz was the culprit. AFAIK, GNOME uses X11 (I saw it in system-monitor) and compiz was gone. So that's maybe why. If anybody knows how to get Plank's "Pressure Reveal" work in Compiz then I'll set you as the accepted answer. Thanks!